# Optional Parameters in Snowflake Stored Procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Are we able to call Snowflake stored procedures with optional parameters?
For example, the B param will be optional.

```
create procedure my_proc(A VARCHAR, B VARCHAR (optional))
```

Comment: @felipe Hoffa,           
Can you advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Standard method is to make many Stored Procedures, and have the lesser call the more with the "defaults supplied"

And Snowflake supported [overloading stored procedure names](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#label-example-overloading-stored-procedure-names) also

so for Javascript SP that might look like:

```
create procedure my_proc(A VARCHAR, B VARCHAR)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  AS
  $$
    return A + B;
  $$;

create or replace procedure my_proc(A VARCHAR)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  AS
  $$
 
      var cmd = "call my_proc(:1, 'abc')";
      var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
              {
              sqlText: cmd,
              binds: [A]
              }
              );
    var result1 = stmt.execute();
    result1.next();
    return result1.getColumnValue(1);
  $$;
```

```
  call my_proc('123');
```

| MY_PROC |
| --- |
| 123abc |

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version [7.41](https://docs.snowflake.com/release-notes/2023/7_41#udfs-and-stored-procedures-support-for-optional-arguments) it is possible to use optional arguments for UDF and stored procedures.

Default(optional) arguments are marked with `DEFAULT <value>`:

```
create or replace procedure my_proc(A VARCHAR, B VARCHAR DEFAULT 'TEST')
returns varchar
language sql
as
BEGIN
  RETURN A || ': ' || B;
END;
```

SP invocation can use named or positional parameters:

```
CALL my_proc(a => 'some value');
-- some value: TEST

CALL my_proc('some value');
-- some value: TEST
```

---

Sidenote:  Required argument cannot follow optional argument. The signature like below is invalid:

```
my_proc(A VARCHAR DEFAULT 'TEST', B VARCHAR )
```