# Snowflake stored procedure parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can not set parameters as default null in snowflake stored procedure. My example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
    TABLE_SCHEMAS STRING DEFAULT NULL,
    TABLE_NAMES STRING DEFAULT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP_STRING STRING
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
...
```

Comment: Optional arguments are [supported from 7.41.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71748900/optional-parameters-in-snowflake-stored-procedures/77488673#77488673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of time of writing Snowflake Data Cloud does not support default values for stored procedure parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
    TABLE_SCHEMAS STRING,
    TABLE_NAMES STRING,
    TIMESTAMP_STRING STRING
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
...
```

Option 1: Pass explicitly `NULL` value to stored procedure call:

```
 CALL MY_PROCEDURE(TABLE_SCHEMAS => NULL,
                   TABLE_NAMES => NULL,
                   TIMESTAMP_STRING  => 'some_value');
```

Option 2: Create overloaded versions of stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
        TIMESTAMP_STRING STRING,
        TABLE_SCHEMAS STRING,
        TABLE_NAMES STRING
    )


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
        TIMESTAMP_STRING STRING,
        TABLE_SCHEMAS STRING
    )

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
        TIMESTAMP_STRING STRING
    )
```

[Overloading procedures and functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf-stored-procedure-naming-conventions#overloading-procedures-and-functions)

> Snowflake supports overloading procedures and functions. In a given schema, you can define multiple procedures or functions that have the same name but different signatures. The signatures must differ by the number of arguments, the types of the arguments, or both